# Event for reclicking local anchor

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Clicking on a link to a local anchor can be detected via `window.onhashchange()` *if* it involves a change to the URL hash.

However, I notice at least in Chrome (I have not checked this with other browsers), if you then scroll around the page and select a link to the same local anchor again, any `onclick` handler for the link fires, then the page jumps to to the anchor, but obviously `onhashchange()` does not fire, and neither does `window.onload()`.  The reason this is significant is both of these would fire *after* the move to the anchor, whereas the link `onclick` handler fires *before.*

So: Is there a correlate to `onload()` for jumping to a local anchor that is already indicated in the URL hash?

Comment: The `hashchange` event obviously won't fire when the hash didn't change, and you clicked the same link ?

Comment: @adeneo Yes -- although I imagine the same would apply if it were a different link to the same anchor.  The page isn't reloaded, so there's no `onload()` event.  The URL doesn't change, so there's no event for that.  But it moves the page, and I need a handler for *after* that move occurs.

Comment: There is no handler for that, but unless you're using some sort of smooth scrolling plugin, it happens right away, and the `click` handler should do.

Comment: The problem is the click handler happens *before* the move.  I'm using `onhashchange()` to [compensate for a top bar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39325205/1151724).  This happens *after* the  move to the anchor, so it is simple to then scroll down a bit.  However, scrolling down via `onclick` then having the page move to an anchor is pointless.

Comment: I guess the only options are to do the scrolling yourself, then you'd now when it's done scrolling, or use a timeout and guesstimate when the scrolling is done.

Comment: Hmmm -- will try a timeout and post if it works.  Thanks.

Comment: @adeneo Sheesh I might as well scrap the whole `onhashchange` deal and just use that >_<

Comment: Okay, you're welcome I guess ?

Comment: @adeneo If you want to add it as an answer please do and I'll give it the tick -- otherwise I'll wait an hour or so and do it for similarly lost sailors of the future.

Comment: Write a good answer explaning what you did, and how it solved your problem, with some code etc. and that's fine with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no event for this, but since the page isn't reloaded it is possible to use a timeout in an `onclick` handler for the link to wait until after the page has moved, e.g.,

```
link.onclick = function () {
    setTimeout (
        function () {
            // Do whatever after the jump.
        }, 100
    )
}
```

A tenth of a second is not very noticeable and probably plenty of time for the shift.  If you use 1/4 or 1/2 second, the gap should be noticeable, which may or may not be desirable as a quick clue if "do whatever" is something the user is going to notice happening.